# attribute is not displayed as an option when adding a new configurable product

Tags: configurable-product, product-attribute

I've added a new attribute. It's setup exactly the same way another attribute is that works fine. It doesn't show up as an option when I add a new configurable product. I've refreshed and cleared the cache.

Comment: did you set it up to be used for configurable products?

Comment: yes the required settings are in place

Comment: Can you post your settings?

Comment: did you add the attribute to an attributeset?

Comment: stefan no it was not added to aset neither was the working attribute and it works fine.

@marius here are the settings 
http://s29.postimg.org/4oiydg6nr/Capture.jpg

Comment: I think @StefanBothner. Is on to something. You need to add the attribute to an attribute set and you will be able to use it for configurable products that belong to that attribute set.

Comment: @user14396 - add it to an attribute set and within this set to an area in product edit form. clear cache, and youll see you can use it!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use it as an option for configurable product you must choose it when you initially create the product. You can't just add it later (unless you want to change database records manually). I recommend that you just create new configurable product. BTW, make sure your new attribute is in chosen attribute set first.